# Django using reverse OneToOne in filter?

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models:

```
class CustomUser(models.Model):
    ...
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.models.OneToOneField(CustomUser)
    fielda = models.IntegerField()
```

I'm trying to perform a filter query based on the value of a field on the Profile model from the CustomUser model but it's giving me the error `name 'profile' is not defined`

```
CustomUser.objects.all().select_related('profile').filter(profile.fielda=0)
```

I need to start the selection from CustomUser model because I have to prefetch other models with FK to CustomUser so I cannot simply start from Profile model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One uses two consecutive underscores (`__`) to look "through" a relation, so you can filter with:

```
CustomUser.objects.filter(profile__fielda=0)
```

The above will thus retrieve all `CustomUser`s with a related `Profile` object where `fielda` is `0`.

Note that the `.select_related(..)` is *not* necessary for filtering. This is only used if you want to *fetch* the data into memory as well.